# Why is this java application hang/freezing?

Tags: java

I am currently writing a code that calculates PI and E to the nth term. I enter a number in TermsJTextField, choose PI or E radio button (only one button can be active at a time), press calculate, and it's supposed to display the answer in the appropriate. However, when I press calculate, the application goes in a hang, and none of the buttons are responsive, even the x button. And the answer is never displayed.

Here's the code. I've narrowed down to the part that gives me a headache:

```
    private void CalculateJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    final double MAX_VALUE = 10000; //Max value
    double Start, End;              //Star and end time
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal ("0");  // Constants for result
    BigDecimal Error = new BigDecimal ("0");   // And Error
    DecimalFormat integerFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.");
    Start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int Terms;
    int count = 1;

    boolean PIchecked = PiJRadioButton.isSelected();
    boolean Echecked = EJRadioButton.isSelected();
    double PI = 0;
    double E = 1;
    try
    {
        Terms = Integer.parseInt(TermsJTextField.getText());
        if ((Terms <= 2) || (Terms >= 10000)) // This checks for the number of terms
        {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
        else
        {
            if (PIchecked) // If Pi butoon is selected, do the following calculation
            {
                for (int i =1 ; 1 <= (Terms);i++)
                {
                    count++;
                    result = result.add(new BigDecimal (Math.pow((-1.0),count)/(2*i-1)));
                }
            EJRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            result = result.multiply(new BigDecimal (4.0));
            Error = new BigDecimal(Math.abs(PI-result.doubleValue())/PI * 100.0);
            }
        else if (Echecked) // This calculates nth term for E
        {   
            result = new BigDecimal("0");
                long factorial = 1L;

                for (int i = 1; i < Terms ; i++)
                {
                    factorial *= i;
                    result = result.add(new BigDecimal(1.0/factorial));
                }
                result = result.add(new BigDecimal(1L));
                Error = new BigDecimal(Math.abs(E-result.doubleValue())/E * 100.0);
            PiJRadioButton.setSelected(false);

        }

                   End = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Time in ms to calculate the answer

    //Output
    DecimalFormat Number = new DecimalFormat("#####0.##");
    if (PIchecked)
    {
        EJTextField.setText("");
        PIJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        ErrorJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(Error + "%"));
    }
    else
    {
        PIJTextField.setText("");
        EJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        ErrorJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(Error + "%"));
    }
    PrintJButton.setEnabled(true);
    PrintJMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
    TimeJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(End-Start));
    }
    }


    catch(NumberFormatException exp)

      {

          Object ERROR_MESSAGE = null;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Don't be silly; Enter a vaule between 2 and 10000", 
              "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 TermsJTextField.selectAll();
                 TermsJTextField.setText("");
                 TermsJTextField.requestFocus();
            }          

}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger or profiler to find out where the program is spending most of its time? The unresponsive part is probably you just trying to do too much on the app thread.

Comment: Also keep a close look on your loops ... especially on the finish conditions

Comment: It seems that your code is running with too much iterations may be infinity, there should be a break or limit condition to stop execution

Comment: Okay, after running the profiler (Thanks, Carcigenicate!), I found out this was the line that the application was having trouble with  <br/>     **result = result.add(new BigDecimal (Math.pow((-1.0),count)/(2*i-1)));**

Comment: Trim your code down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your termination condition for your for-loop will never complete, as seen below:

```
for (int i =1 ; 1 <= (Terms);i++)
```

Switching it to the following should fix it (changed `1` to `i`):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Terms; i++)
```

Comment: @Robert `1` was changed to `i`, fixing the terminating condition.

Comment: Tried it, but now it's not recognizing an appropriate number (3,15,4, etc)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: This app is supposed to use try-catch statement to detect if the user enters a string, or a number not within the range.  <br/> I meant to say those numbers in the range are caught by the exception

Comment: I recommend you debug it with print statements, as this isn't something I can compile and test myself.

Comment: @sgy0003 your question is answered, if you got another issue with your code, please open up another question with it.